# What does 'made' mean in "In his case there is no idle eloquence, no made,[...]"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, nouns

In *[A Plea for Captain John Brown](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2567/pg2567-images.html)*, Thoreau writes:

> He was too fair a specimen of a man to represent the like of us.
> Who, then, were his constituents? If you read his words understandingly
> you will find out. In his case there is no idle eloquence, no **made**, nor maiden speech,
> no compliments to the oppressor.

I have done [some research](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/made), yet the meaning of **made** in this
sentence remains unclear to me. Is it used here as a noun, meaning grub / maggot? Or may it mean here written / composed, describing thus the word *speech*?

Comment: It seems to me closer to the meaning of the preceding "maiden" ("no made, nor maiden speech").

Comment: *made* means *artificial* and a *maiden speech* is restrained. So there is neither artificial nor restrained speech.

Answer (score 7):

"Made" modifies "speech", which is ellipted: "no made speech, nor maiden speech".

The meaning seems to be the following.

> (SOED) **made** **3** Artificially constructed or produced; contrived, arranged

Comment: It seems a pretty disparate coordination.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, but that's Thoreau for you. :)

Comment: Disparate, but poetic (because of the phonetic similarity between *made* and *maiden*). I would assume this is the effect Thoreau was aiming for.

Comment: It would be easier to parse that way had it been punctuated differently, e.g. “…no idle eloquence; no made, nor maiden speech; no compliments…”

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation would be that, as part of the clause "*no made, nor maiden speech*", Thoreau emphasises the directness of the man's speech: *no made speech*. The quote you give is succeeded by the following:

> Truth is his inspirer, and earnestness the polisher of his sentences.

The captain's words, I think Thoreau says here, were not [prepared](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/made), not thought out in advance.

Comment: Perhaps 'no speech, whether maturely prepared or youthfully naive'?